# Comparator function for upper_bound or lower_bound for vector of vector

Tags: c++, algorithm

How(is it possible) to write a compartor function for upper_bound for a vector of vector such that it compares all indexes of inner vector and get a element in which corresponding element are larger

For example for a given arr

```
vector<vector<int>>arr={{0,1,1},{0,1,2},{0,2,1},{1,2,3},{4,1,2},{4,3,2}}
```

the upper bound of {0,1,1} should give {1,2,3} i.e. all corresponding element should be larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that the predicate you have in mind is "all values in the inner vectors must be greater".

`upper_bound` requires a vector of data that [is partitioned](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) with respect to the given sample.

In the given example, the data vector is not partitioned w.r.t. `{0,1,1}` (and the assumed predicated), hence, you cannot even use `upper_bound`.

The answer is, therefore: The problem and the proposed solution are incompatible. Stated differently:

> is it possible

No.